# É possível deixar a Workspace do VsCode "Responsiva" igual o Sublime?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Ao utilizar do VsCode em metade da tela [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHx0K.png), se cria um scroll horizontal que mostra o que há além da margem direita. Não existe isso no Sublime pois ele se adapta ao tamanho da tela [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LOui.png). Seria possível a mesma ação no Vs?

Comment: você pode usar o atalho: Alt+Z

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem como sim vc tem que habilitar o `Word Wrap` nos `Setting`, assim ele vai "quebrar as linhas" e não vai ter esse `scroll` horizontal

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou se vc preferir pode usar o atalho para ativar e desativar o `Word Wrap`. No iOS é `Option+Z` no Windows acredito que seja `Ctrl+Z` ou `Alt+Z` tem que ver no seu ShortCurt como está definido...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Também tem essa opção de toggle wordwrap no menu View, que é como eu costumo usar

Comment: @Isac boa! Não sabia que tinha como mudar por outro lugar ;)